# Union of 2 objects with Lodash?

Tags: lodash

I have 2 objects:

```
var obj1 = { a:1, b:2, c:3 };
var obj2 = { a:4, c:5, d:6 };
```

How could I get the union of these 2 objects with lodash? I expect the result to be:

{ a:4, c:5 }

Comment: Do you mean the union or the intersection of the object keys? Because what you specified looks like the intersection.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-line and readable snippet:

```
_.pick(obj2, _.intersection(_.keys(obj1), _.keys(obj2)))

// {a: 4, c: 5}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ze8g0p22/